# Mongoose ignore parent if ref is null

Tags: mongodb-query, nodes, mongoose-schema

I have one scchema registrations and other events, I wants to ignore the registration for which events ref is null,

There is the code:

`Registrations.find({}).populate('events',{_id:'63ff4f974b030baef5025ce3'}).populate('tags');`

Thanks

I am using mongoose for the execution.

Comment: Can you explain the thing you want to do and the problem you have in a better way?

Comment: I wants to ignore all those records for which events come as empty array(), even if events come as empty but still it will show the registered user